# FFmpeg - pts and dts not increasing properly for video, but does for audio

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to take two videos and put them together into one video. However, when I run my code, I get this error when decoding/encoding the second video:

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0
```

When the code finishes, the first video is completely fine, but the second video is not. The best result that I have been able to produce is where the second half of the second video comes right after the first video. The funny thing is, the audio is completely fine and is as it should be.

In the past, I have been able to use my decoding/encoding code to simply copy a video (both video and audio).

I have searched online regarding this specific problem and tried the suggested solutions, but none of them seem to fix my issue. These are the threads that I have been looking at:

[FFmpeg - What does non monotonically increasing dts mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231348/ffmpeg-what-does-non-monotonically-increasing-dts-mean)

[How to use libavformat to concat 2 video files with same codec (re-muxing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282600/how-to-use-libavformat-to-concat-2-video-files-with-same-codec-re-muxing)

[Non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136872/non-monotonically-increasing-dts-to-muxer-in-stream)

This is the current code that I have written:

Video and ClipSequence structs:

```
typedef struct Video {
    char* filename;
    AVFormatContext* inputContext;
    AVFormatContext* outputContext;
    AVCodec* videoCodec;
    AVCodec* audioCodec;
    AVStream* inputStream;
    AVStream* outputStream;
    AVCodecContext* videoCodecContext_I; // Input
    AVCodecContext* audioCodecContext_I; // Input
    AVCodecContext* videoCodecContext_O; // Output
    AVCodecContext* audioCodecContext_O; // Output
    int videoStream;
    int audioStream;
    SwrContext* swrContext;
} Video;

typedef struct ClipSequence {
    VideoList* videos;
    AVFormatContext* outputContext;
    AVStream* outputStream;
    int64_t lastpts, lastdts;
    int64_t currentpts, currentdts;
} ClipSequence;
```

Decoding and encoding (same code for audio):

```
int decodeVideoSequence(ClipSequence* sequence, Video* video, AVPacket* packet, AVFrame* frame) {
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(video->videoCodecContext_I, packet);
    if (response < 0) {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to send video packet to decoder\n");
        return response;
    }
    while (response >= 0) {
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(video->videoCodecContext_I, frame);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (response < 0) {
            printf("[ERROR] Failed to receive video frame from decoder\n");
            return response;
        }
        if (response >= 0) {
            // Do stuff and encode
            sequence->currentpts = packet->pts; // Store decoded packet's pts and dts
            sequence->currentdts = packet->dts;
            if (encodeVideoSequence(sequence, video, frame) < 0) {
                printf("[ERROR] Failed to encode new video\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        av_frame_unref(frame);
    }
    return 0;
}

int encodeVideoSequence(ClipSequence* sequence, Video* video, AVFrame* frame) {
    AVPacket* packet = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!packet) {
        printf("[ERROR] Could not allocate memory for video output packet\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int response = avcodec_send_frame(video->videoCodecContext_O, frame);
    if (response < 0) {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to send video frame for encoding\n");
        return response;
    }
    while (response >= 0) {
        response = avcodec_receive_packet(video->videoCodecContext_O, packet);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (response < 0) {
            printf("[ERROR] Failed to receive video packet from encoder\n");
            return response;
        }
        // Set packet to have pts and dts based on the previous video's pts and dts
        packet->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        packet->pts = sequence->currentpts + sequence->lastpts;
        packet->dts = sequence->currentdts + sequence->lastdts;
        packet->stream_index = video->videoStream;
        packet->duration = 1000; // 60 fps
        response = av_interleaved_write_frame(sequence->outputContext, packet);
        if (response < 0) {
            printf("[ERROR] Failed to write video packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    av_packet_unref(packet);
    av_packet_free(&packet);
    return 0;
}
```

Reading the frames:

```
int readSequenceFrames(ClipSequence* sequence, Video* video, AVPacket* packet, AVFrame* frame) {
    if (!packet) {
        printf("[ERROR] Packet not allocated to be read\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (!frame) {
        printf("[ERROR] Frame not allocated to be read\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Sets video and audio codec context parameters
    if (prepareVideoOutStream(video) < 0) {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to prepare output video stream\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (prepareAudioOutStream(video) < 0) {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to prepare output audio stream\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Prepares audio resampling
    if (initResampler(video->audioCodecContext_I, video->audioCodecContext_O, &(video->swrContext)) < 0) {
        printf("[ERROR] Failed to init audio resampler\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Read packets
    int frameNum = 0;
    while (av_read_frame(video->inputContext, packet) >= 0) {
        printf("[READ] Reading frame %i\n", frameNum);
        if (packet->stream_index == video->videoStream) {
            if (decodeVideoSequence(sequence, video, packet, frame) < 0) {
                printf("[ERROR] Failed to decode and encode video\n");
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (packet->stream_index == video->audioStream) {
            if (decodeAudioSequence(sequence, video, packet, frame) < 0) {
                printf("[ERROR] Failed to decode and encode audio\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(packet);
        frameNum++;
    }
    // Increment pts and dts by the last pts and dts in the current video
    sequence->lastpts += sequence->currentpts;
    sequence->lastdts += sequence->currentdts;
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that I have the right logic when I am increasing the pts and dts. I am not sure what exactly that I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   // Increment pts and dts by the last pts and dts in the current video
    sequence->lastpts += sequence->currentpts;
    sequence->lastdts += sequence->currentdts;
```

This is wrong. First, ignore PTS for now and only deal with DTS.

DTS is not a relative number, it's an absolute number. Adding incrementing numbers together creates an exponential sequence. For example: if this is a 30 fps video, and the time base is 1/30, the every frame the DTS will advance by one. e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9

If you keep adding them together, you will get: 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45

So, `sequence->lastdts = sequence->currentdts;` not `sequence->lastdts += sequence->currentdts;`

When you set the new DTS, you need to add in a frame duration
e.g. `packet->dts = sequence->lastdts + frame_duration;`

Otherwise this frame will have the same DTS as the previous frame, when it needs to be 1 frame more

Next PTS:

PTS is not monotonic and can go backwards in time. You and can not track it this way because the next PTS may be a lower time stamp. To solve this you need to convert PTS to CTS, and then back:

```
auto cts = packet->pts - packet->dts
packet->dts = // Whatever you are updating the dts to
packet->pts = packet->dts + cts
```

Also setting `packet->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;` on every frame will cause problems when seeking

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just a note, however: I was calling `sequence->lastdts += sequence->currentdts;` after all packets in each video were finished being read. This line was correct when I tried putting three and four videos together. I can see how `sequence->lastdts = sequence->currentdts;` would suffice if I only were combining two videos.